# C++ Decorator - Not working properly

Tags: c++, decorator

First Issue Resolved

As voiced in the answers below , i incorrectly wrote the

```
#ifndef ICETOWER_H
#define ICETOWER_H
```

I'm still having some problem with my c++ code.

I implemented a decorator pattern to upgrade a basic tower to an ice tower with 2* the cost. but when i run it , its displaying the same specs for both towers even after it has been decorated . Anyone have any idea what i did wrong ?

Here are the files :

**tower.h**

```
#ifndef __TOWER_H__
#define __TOWER_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Tower {

private:

    string type;
    string effect;
    int cost;
    int sellTower;
    int damage;
    int range;
    int rate;

public:

    string getType() { return type; }
    string getEffect() { return effect; }

    int getCost() { return cost; }
    int getSale() { return sellTower; }
    int getDamage() { return damage; }
    int getRange() { return range; }
    int getROF() { return rate; }

    Tower();
    virtual ~Tower(){}
};

#endif __TOWER_H__
```

**tower.cpp**

```
#include "Tower.h"

Tower::Tower()
{
    // Tower Type
    this->type = "Basic";

    // Tower Special Effect
    this->effect = "None";

    // Tower Cost
    this->cost = 500;

    // Tower Sell Cost
    this->sellTower = 300;

    // Tower Damage inflicted
    this->damage = 50;

    // Tower Range (paths)
    this->range = 2;

    // Tower rate of fire
    this->rate = 0.5;
};
```

**TowerDecorator.h**

```
#ifndef __TOWERDECORATOR_H__
#define __TOWERDECORATOR_H__
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Tower.h"
using namespace std;

class TowerDecorator : public Tower {

private:

    Tower *decoratedTower;

public:

    TowerDecorator(Tower *decoratedTower)
    {
        this->decoratedTower = decoratedTower;
    }

    string type() { return decoratedTower->getType(); }
    string effect() { return decoratedTower->getEffect(); }

    int getCost() { return decoratedTower->getCost(); }
    int getSale() { return decoratedTower->getSale(); }
    int getDamage() { return decoratedTower->getDamage(); }
    int getRange() { return decoratedTower->getRange(); }
    int getROF() { return decoratedTower->getROF(); }

};

#endif __TOWERDECORATOR_H__
```

**iceTower.h**

```
#ifndef ICETOWER_H
#define ICETOWER_H

#include "TowerDecorator.h"

class IceTower : public TowerDecorator {

public:
    IceTower(Tower *decoratedTower) : TowerDecorator (decoratedTower){}

    int getCost(){return TowerDecorator::getCost() * 2;}
};

#endif __ICETOWER_H__
```

**Driver.cpp**

```
#include "Tower.h"
#include "TowerDecorator.h"
#include "IceTower.h"

void printTowerDetails(Tower* tower)
{
    cout << endl << "This is a " << tower->getType() << " Tower" << endl;
    cout << "Build Tower : " << tower->getCost() << " Coins" << endl;
    cout << "Sell Tower : " << tower->getSale() << " Coins" << endl;
    cout << "Tower Range : " << tower->getRange() << " paths" << endl;
    cout << "Tower Rate Of Fire : " << tower->getROF() << " p/s" << endl;
    cout << "Tower Special Effect : " << tower->getEffect() << "" << endl;
}

int main() {

    Tower *t1 = new Tower();

    printTowerDetails(t1);

    t1 = new IceTower(t1);

    printTowerDetails(t1);


}
```

**Output** :

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNHKS.png

[image: error]

Comment: In Tower.h and TowerDecorator.h the include gaurds that you define are different from the one that you put in ifdef

Comment: @Jimmy See my answer about one more your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two serious errors. 
The first one is that you check definitions of manifest constants with suffix `_H__` but define them without the suffix:

```
#ifndef __TOWER_H__
#define __TOWER__
```

and

```
#ifndef __TOWERDECORATOR_H__
#define __TOWERDECORATOR__
```

The second one is that you forgot to place a semicolon after class definition of `TowerDecorator`

```
class TowerDecorator : public Tower {
//...
}
```

Comment: @kec - i'm getting the same output for the 2 towers tho. Any idea why the decorator pattern doesnt seem to work . The cost for the second output should have been 1000

Comment: Tower *t1 = new Tower();

 printTowerDetails(t1);

 t1 = new IceTower(t1);

 printTowerDetails(t1);

Comment: thanks - it works now but the decorator doesnt seem to wrk . its displaying the same specs for both outputs

Comment: @Jimmy  Should function getCost be declared as virtual in class Tower?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first problem that you have is a problem with your include guard. It should be:

```
#ifndef __TOWER_H__
#define __TOWER_H__
```

You might have other problems as well.

BTW, you shouldn't use names that begin with two underscores, since they are reserved.

Comment: Thanks , it fixed the main issue but i'm still getting an error with this line (added it in the main post)

Comment: class IceTower : public TowerDecorator {

Comment: Two consecutive underscores anywhere are forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Your header gaurds are inconsistent:-

```
#ifndef __TOWER_H__
#define __TOWER__
```

This should be

```
#ifndef __TOWER_H__
#define __TOWER_H__
```

Secondly change this

```
#endif __TOWER_H__
```

to

```
#endif
```

Comment: Inlcude guards with double underscores are invalid, because such identifier tokens are reserved for the compiler. A correct guard would be `TOWER_H`.

Comment: But he's also appending two underscores, so that would not be a problem

Comment: Huh? The trailing double-underscore is a second problem, same as the leading ones are. The position of the underscores is not significant.